# Git flow for dev and production with github and vps

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, debian

I know the git basics. I have read a lot of tutorials and understand how it works.
But I couldn't find a specific VPS implementation post for my situation.
I want to build a git staging flow where there is two environments or repositories (dev and production) cloned from the same github repository.
I'm inclined to use the branching flow, so my implementation is something like this:

**GITHUB REPOSITORY (private):**

`github.com/username/repositoryname.git`

**VPS:**


Two cloned directories from the github repository:

`/var/www/dev.domain.com/public_html/repositoryName`

`/var/www/domain.com/public_html/repositoryName`

When I need to add a feature, bugfix, etc. I create a branch in `/var/www/dev.domain.com/public_html/repositoryName` from its develop branch and modify files using netbeans git plugin. When I'm done, I just commit, merge to master and delete temporary branch.
Then, I have to pull into the github repository, merge there and perform a pull from the /var/www/domain.com/public_html/repositoryName` (production repository directory).
How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is the problem. Are you asking how to pull changes to your "dev" environment? You need to just go there and do "git pull". Or are you asking how to automate that process? Or it's unclear how exactly the whole flow with branches and environments should work?

Comment: @BorisSerebrov, thanks for answering. The simplified flow I'm thinking is: branch "dev" environment, push to git repository, pull git into production (the gis repository in the web folder without subdomain). Does it make sense?

Comment: So you are asking about the general flow, I posted my reply as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about the overall flow, it can be like this:

1. Create special `production` branch which will be used on your production server; and you can use "master" as development branch for your staging server.
2. Prepare you dev environment: clone the repository and leave it on `master` branch
3. Prepare your production environment: clone the repository and do `git checkout production`
4. Development process:

   - `git checkout master`
   - `git checkout -b branch-for-my-current-task`
   - `git add ...` / `git commit ...`
   - `git push -u origin HEAD`
   - repeat if necessary until it's ready to push to staging
5. Merge and deploy to staging:

   - Merge your branch back to master - if you use github then you create and merge the pull request from your branch to master
   - Go to your staging server (or the folder with stating app sources) and do `git pull`, restart your app (ideally this step should be automated, so when you merge to master on github, your app is updated automatically)
6. Test your app on staging
7. Merge and deploy to production:

   - Merge `master` to `production` branch - again, on github you crate a pull request from `master` branch to `production` and merge it
   - Go you your production server and do `git pull`

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. I have a question: how do i "leave it in master branch"? I just stand in dev.domain.com/ and do a `git checkout master`?

Comment: I think when you'll clone the repository, it will be on `master`, but yes, you can explicitly do `git checkout master` to make sure.